# Storing image files directly to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I don't need gridFs as my images file won't be more than 16mb for sure. I also don't need file storage like s3 which I used for most of the project.

I have confusion with using bson data to directly store the image to mongodb document. Says I don't have a file from client, I have just an image link like example.com/v1/myImg.jpge, what should I do first? convert the images to base64 and then store it as binary type?

Comment: A base64 would be a string, but yes, that is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably fetch the whole file, and then either convert them to base64 and store it in a string, or, *don't* convert it to base64 and store it as Binary. The latter uses less space. You can wrap your data directly in Binary() - without the base64 conversion. See the docs at https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/binary.html

Comment: what is the different btw base64 and binary? I thought image is best always in base64? I always use base64 image when i was using PHP.

Comment: base64 encodes binary data as a string. For every 3 original bytes, it needs four base64 characters, increasing the size by ⅓rd. Some languages/databases aren't great with binary data in specific contexts, and there base64 encoding makes sense. It's not needed for MongoDB (as long as you wrap it in Binary()).